# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, error-handling, attributes

I am getting the following error when I am trying to convert the output of a SQL query into a dataframe in jupyter notebook. I have already checked other posts on similar topic, but this is a different error. Can someone please explain why this is happening.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
k =  %sql select * from table1
df = k.DataFrame()
```

> Error:  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: `K` is already a dataframe

Comment: Thank you Chrus2

Answer (score 0):

k is already an object of DataFrame.

Always check with
type(object)
type(k)

this will give you what type of object it is. Based on that you can further try to convert as required.

Just a suggestion, going further if you want to convert a variable into DataFrame, use pd.DataFrame.

> In your case df = pd.DataFrame(k) if it was not a dataframe object